# How do I build a USB joystick/button encoder board without using an Arduino or Teensy

Tags: circuit-design, usb-device

I am making a macro keys button box and need something to convert the buttons into keyboard inputs on a PC, such as a shortcut key in a game.

Previously I have used an Arduino Pro Micro, although in order to make it more professional, I am wanting to make a custom PCB with terminals for the buttons to easily connect to. I then want to make a computer app that easily allows me to change the buttons. I am considering using a Atmega32U4 chip to control everything and then simply have terminals for buttons which go to ground and a pin on the chip.

- Is this a good way to do this and how would I actually program it?
- Would it be as simple as uploading the Arduino firmware and then uploading my own sketch to it, or is it more complicated than this?

I basically want to make a USB Joystick Encoder which I can program the buttons with my own app. Although, rather then purchasing a USB Joystick Encoder, I want to make the PCB and solder on the parts myself.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. (1) Your "question" is way too broad for this site. You're really asking for a complete design and we're not a free design service. (2) You didn't ask a question. (There is no question mark in your post.) (3) For your question to remain open you'll need to edit it down to one specific, answerable, technical question.

Comment: With reference to point (2) in the comment above, I've now added some punctuation, including the missing question marks. As mentioned, they weren't there originally.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it working with an Arduino, the obvious next step is to use the same microcontroller and the same or similar software.

ATmegas can be programmed using a SPI programmer like STK500 or USBasp. You could load your software directly that way, or just load the Arduino boot loader and use the Arduino loader to load your software.